# WCF service settings problem. I added .svc handler in IIS but it keeps disappearing

Tags: wcf, iis, configuration, handler, web-services

my web service was working, then suddenly it stopped.  After debugging I realized that there might be a problem in the config, and for some reason the .svc mapping was gone in IIS (Handler Mappings).

I added the .svc mapping, and it is now updating my web.config and adding a node to the web.config (my previous web.config's didn't have this node and it was working just fine).

Ok, so I then upload my original web.config, now going back to IIS it shows that the .svc mapping is deleted again.

Has anyone else experienced this strange behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Work-around RC1 problem - Manually map .svc to aspnet_isapi.dll

see:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/054b1d90-1e75-42ff-8d18-639f0b273dad/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using IIS7 since your web.config keeps getting changed.  Can you post the code that gets added to your web.config?

Also, are you setting this mapping at the application level in IIS?  If so, you (or someone else) might be changing mappings at a higher level (or lower if you are working higher) which caused the initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any special or custom behavior consider using the Factory attribute of @ServiceHost, you then won't need any config...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967286.aspx